# How to get <li> items from HTML with their Index into a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a reorder list using Sortable jQuery. After the reorder, I want to get the new Order of LI Items. How can I achieve this?

```
<li id="A1" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li id="A2" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li id="A3" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li id="A4" class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
```

Comment: You mean `.index()`? It [works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/BrCuN/) to return the actual index of element based by its id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you an array of objects containing the ID and index of each li:

```
var order = $('li').map(function(i) { 
    return { id: this.id, index: i };
}).get();
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/czprf/

Answer (score 0):

Selecting them with jQuery will get them in their new order:

```
var myLis = $('.ui-state-default');

myLis.eq(0).html(); // This will return Item 2
myLis.eq(1).html(); // This will return Item 3
myLis.eq(2).html(); // This will return Item 4
myLis.eq(3).html(); // This will return Item 5
```

jQuery always selects the elements closest to the top of the DOM first.

Comment: But I don't know How many <li> tags will be there. In this case wat should I do?

Comment: You can loop through them with `each`: `myLis.each(function(index) {...`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
<ul id="AAA">
  <li id="A1" class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li id="A2" class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li id="A3" class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
var nodeList = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById('AAA').children ),
      liRef = document.getElementsByClassName('match')[0];    
console.log( nodeList.indexOf( liRef ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to access the `stop` event of the sortable plugin.

```
var order;
$('#sortable').sortable({
    stop: function(){
        order = $('#sortable li').map(function(i, li){
            return {index: i, id: li.id, text: li.innerHTML};
        });
        console.log(order);
    }
});
```

[Here's your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeAe2/);